# Microsoft Reports Adding Two Column Values

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportbuilder

Is it possible to add two column values say I have 3 columns:

```
Item 1                |    Item 2                |  Total

=Fields!Item1.Value   |   =Fields!Item1.Value    |   ???
```

What I want to avoid (for maintainability reasons) is doing something like this:

```
=Fields!Item1.Value + Fields!Item2.Value
```

I am rather looking for something like

```
Column1Value + Column2Value
```

Thanks Guys!!!!

Comment: Is this coming from a database of some sort and if so, why is it not possible to get the total in a query?

Comment: This is coming from a webservice and the dataset is a list of custom objects. I can implement the total logic in the object itself but it only makes sense in the report so I was avoiding doing the totals in the objects, since I am gonna end up with "heaps of new total properties" in that object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do this by adding a calculated field in your dataset. So add your two source fields, lets call them *Item1* and *Item2*, normally - with their *Source* set to the name of the field in the data source.  Then add a calculated field, letss call it *Total* to the report dataset by setting the Field's *Expression* to *=Fields!Item1.Value + Fields!Item2.Value*.
Then anywhere in your report you can access the calculated value by using =Fields!Total.Value.

This way you get your calculation without modifying the underlying datasource, it is more maintainable (the calculation in one place) it simplifies referencing the calculation throughout the report.

Comment: This works until those Field Names in the query change. You are right back to using the Fields, which is what the OP said they did NOT want to do. So this is not the answer.  You still need to use ReportItems.  Change the value of your Field names and let me know how it works out.

Comment: Actually those fields names used in expressions (i.e. Fields!Item1, Fields!Item2) are entirely controlled by the report author and specified in the report's DataSet elements. The underlying field names of the data source are specifed in the RDL Field element's "Source". So the report DataSet's field can be Item1 but it could be bound to a field in the datasource with a different name.

Comment: Yes, like I said, change the datasource's field name and let me know what happens.  When you reference the report items, it can change from "CustomerTotal" to "CusTotalAmt" and it still works because the actual values of the text box's are being added, not the value of the field names.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like what you would like to do is reference the value of the report object (the textbox) rather than the column from the query.  You can do this by using ReportItems!.

When you drag out the column from the dataset, it may name the text box after the column, if the column name can vary you will want to assign a static value to the text box in which the value will appear.

So, in the initial example you gave, you will have textboxes by the names of Item1, Item2, and Total.  Thus, in the appropriate Total textbox you will want:

```
=ReportItems!Item1.Value + ReportItems!Item2.Value
```

or if you named the textboxes Red and Blue it would be:

```
=ReportItems!Red.Value + ReportItems!Blue.Value
```

[image]
[image]

A list of available ReportItems will pop up when you hit '!' after ReportItems.

Comment: I just used this to do some variable formatting, like if the Total is 3 then the background goes purple. I was tired of typing the expression twice, once for the value and once for the color. This made maintenance hard too. Now I just do IIF(ReportItems!Total.Value=3,...). Thanks to D.S. for the answer and to Luis for the question!

Answer (score 3):

I would just do the addition in the query and return it as a calculated field.

e.g.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field1 + field2 AS total;
```

I don't see the maintainability problem with this. If you need to keep the query separate from everything else, consider stored procedures or some sort of factory to generate the query.

Comment: I am using Custom Business Objects and those totals dont make sense to the object but only to the report itself, I want to avoid having to calculate that in the object itself..if possible, if not then I will have to go with the suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use a [matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334.aspx), the behavior you seek is inbuilt.

Comment: Humm..not in my particular case as Those totals are not the total of a line but rather from 2 columns, meaning I can have a fourth column that I don't want included in the total. Hope this makes sense.